# How to find rows from df where all elements from search list exists all?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a df which contains columns product id and product names. The product names column is tokenized and in list format.
For example:

```
Product id  Product name
1            [land, cruiser]
1            [land, cruiser]
1            [land, cruiser, toyota]
1            [land, cruiser]
1            [land, toyota]
```

and `search_word = [land, cruiser]`
and I want to select all rows where all elements from `search_word` exist.
So, the result should be

```
     Product id  Product name
    1            [land, cruiser]
    1            [land, cruiser]
    1            [land, cruiser]
```

Currently, I wrote this code:

```
has_all = data[
        data['Product name'].apply(lambda x: np.all([*map(lambda l: l in x, search_words)]))]
```

How can I speed up this line (around 4.2 bln rows)?
In this case, working as a list is faster or as a string using the `re` library?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` operations and a list comprehension.

Assuming this input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Product id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                   'Product name': [['land', 'cruiser'],
                                    ['land', 'cruiser'],
                                    ['land', 'cruiser', 'toyota'],
                                    ['land', 'cruiser'],
                                    ['land', 'toyota']]})

# use a set instead of a list!
search_word = set(['land', 'cruiser'])
```

You can use:

```
df2 = df[[search_word == set(x) for x in df['Product name']]]
```

output:

```
   Product id     Product name
0           1  [land, cruiser]
1           1  [land, cruiser]
3           1  [land, cruiser]
```